# Add UTM and Referral Links to AR Quick Look

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, quicklook, arquicklook

Attempted to track usage of AR content in S3 (without S3).

Am trying to create referral campaign links in [PixelMe](https://pixelme.me/) .

When opening the content it opens an image of the item and and not the content itself.

Here's an example of a pixelme to USDZ link: https://pxlme.me/WnJ8WjY3
Here's an example of a pixelme to GLB link: https://pxlme.me/wK5w0S7G

Here's an example of the embedded iFrame:

```
<model-viewer style="width:100%;height:100%" src="GLB LINK GOES HERE" 
    ar auto-rotate camera-controls alt="A 3D model designed by us" 
    background-color="#FFF" ios-src="USDZ LINK GOES HERE" magic-leap unstable-webxr>
    </model-viewer>
```

When integrating with [Google's Model Viewer](https://modelviewer.dev/) it says "object could not be opened".

How can I use referral links with AR Quick Look?

Answer (score 1):

The reason something like PixelMe won't work with USDZ and GLB is because Pixelme and any ad targeting/retargeting rely on embedding a line of html into your page that loads a 1x1 pixel image from a remote server.

GLB files are binary files that will serve the images loaded into them. USDZ files are zip files of Pixar's USD format. Neither format supports adding html into it.

If you are looking to track usage of the AR Quick Look use a traditional tool like Google Analytics or any other web analytics tool that can track clicks. The only thing you need to filter for is users running iOS 12+. Any user on iOS 12+ who clicks the link will see the AR Quick Look.

Comment: Thanks Hermes, good to learn how PixelMe works. 

The reason I can't use traditional tracking methods like this is we are trying to do this across multiple sites at once, without our client's having to do anything and report their google analytics back to us. 

If you've any input on how to achieve this I'm all ears.

Comment: could you load the USDZ file from a remote server?

Comment: Have you considered, setting up a Lambda endpoint which could take a parameter or more, log the needed data, and return the appropriate model?